# how to change permalinks format for pagination?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Sorry if my question was basic or stupid. Please help me how to do this in wordpress, i m new to wordpress.

I have permalinks for pagination page like this

```
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html/1
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html/2
```

but i need to change this permalinks as

```
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html?page=1
www.website.com/customtaxonomy.html?page=2
```

only for paginations pages.0

Comment: Remove the crappy `.html` part. That causes huge issues with query variables added to the URL. Best is, remove `.html`, period. `.html` serves absolutely no purpose, so it really really is not even worthwhile writing any piece of decend code to sort the URL for something this useless as an added `.html`